# DateTime Hour Format issue while creating datetime object

Tags: c#, datetime

```
DateTime Temp= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, site.start.Hour, site.start.Minute, 0);
```

`site.start.Hour` is 23

My question is my start hour is 23 but 
**Temp** DateTime Object is showing hour in 12 hour format that is 11 pm. Why  and how to get Temp value in format in which i am passing the value of  site.start.Hour that is 24 hour  format?

Comment: DateTime objects do not have any format stored within. They are stored as a number Ticks. Any format you see is as a result of a conversion to a string (even in the debugger). You should store dates in a date data type, but then format them to the format you need them in when you need to display them. If you haven't changed the thread culture, the format you see will be based upon the current culture of your operating system.

Comment: `site.start.Hour = Temp.Hour`

Answer (score 2):

As others already commented, `DateTime` doesn't store any display information.

When you hover your variable in the Debugger, `ToString()` is called and displays a value for your current Environment. Most likely you are in an environment with 12 hour format.

To get the actual hour, you should use the `Hour` property:

```
DateTime Temp = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, site.start.Hour, site.start.Minute, 0);

//should be 23
var tempHour = Temp.Hour;
```

You have different [format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/az4se3k1(v=vs.85)), which [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) can use. When the additional parameter `IFormatProvider` ([`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) for example) is not given, the string is displayed in the current threads culture.

---

So when you want to display it in a specific culture, use the culture and format string you want:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE") // germany has 24 hour clock for example
var str = Temp.ToString("g", cultureInfo);
```

Generaly, only change the culture, if you only want to display your Date in the specific culture. In most cases, we do not want to limit it, so it's always in the format your user would expect.